# Execute batch file from specific line/part with another batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have 2 files again

```
Script.bat
StartScript.bat
```

The code inside the *Script.bat* file:

```
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
pause
```

I want to make the *StartScript.bat* file to start the *Script.bat* file from specific line/part(from `echo 2` for example)

Somthing like this:

```
Start Script.bat skip line 1
```

or

```
Start Script.bat from line 2
```

Anybody? :/

Comment: Is the premise here that you can't modify `Script.bat`?

Answer (score 3):

If you can edit both files, you can do something like this.

### StartScript.bat

```
@ECHO OFF

IF "%1"=="1" CALL Script.bat 1
IF "%1"=="2" CALL Script.bat 2
IF "%1"=="3" CALL Script.bat 3
```

### Script.bat

```
@ECHO OFF

IF "%1"=="1" GOTO SECTION1
IF "%1"=="2" GOTO SECTION2
IF "%1"=="3" GOTO SECTION3

:SECTION1
  ECHO Section 1

:SECTION2
  ECHO Section 2

:SECTION3
  ECHO Section 3
```

Then calling like this:

```
StartScript.bat 2
```

Would give this result:

```
Section 2
Section 3
```

Comment: not quite an answer to the question, but definitively the better method.

Comment: @Stephan If files can't be edited, then my answer won't work. Is that why you say it's not quite an answer?

Comment: yes. (as you say: "If you can edit both files") Nevertheless +1 because it's the preferable method.

Comment: @Stephan That's cool...I just wanted to make sure I wasn't reading the question incorrectly or a different way.

Answer (score 1):

quite straightforward (although it seems to be a quite strange request):

```
more +1 script.bat >temp.bat
call temp.bat
del temp.bat
```